# Cannot run simple script with WebView Universal Windows App

Tags: windows-phone, win-universal-app

I have simple html file (save in project) load on to WebView. It load success and display "Hello World" header.

### File index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>ABC</title>
<script>
    function SayHello() {
        return "hello";
    };
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

### Load to WebView

```cs
 protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
            webView.Navigate(new Uri("ms-appx-web:///index.html", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

// Exception below line
            var data = await webView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new List<string> { "SayHello();" });
            Debug.WriteLine(data);
        }
```

I don't understand why this happen. It success run on Google Chrome. Am I miss something here?

Comment: And was is exception details?

Comment: just System.Exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSDN about [Navigate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigate.aspx) method:

> Loads the HTML content at the specified Uniform Resource Identifier
>   (URI).

When you call the method, it doesn't instantly load the content, it may take some time. You need to listen to the [DOMContentLoaded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.domcontentloaded.aspx) event and then run the script when page is actually loaded into the WebView.

```
webView1.DOMContentLoaded += webView1_DOMContentLoaded;
...
...
private async void webView1_DOMContentLoaded(WebView sender, WebViewDOMContentLoadedEventArgs args)
{
   var data = await webView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new List<string> { "SayHello();" });
   Debug.WriteLine(data);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should go to Manifest profile in URI,
Windows Runtime Access= All
Type = Include

[image]